# Solving project euler number 6 in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve the [Project Euler problem number 6](http://projecteuler.net/problem=6) with the following program:

```
double counter = 1;
double sumsquare = 0;
double squaresum = 0;
while (counter <= 100)
{
  sumsquare += Math.Pow(counter, 2);
  squaresum += counter;
  counter++;
}
Math.Pow(squaresum, 2);
Console.WriteLine("the sum is {0} ,the square is :{1}", squaresum.ToString(), sumsquare.ToString());
double diff = sumsquare - squaresum;
Console.WriteLine(diff.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, the answer was wrong. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with my code?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn there is no output in the euler questions, you're just correct or not.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn i meant when you enter your answer via the project Euler form, it just tells you wether you're correct or not (usually the answer is just an integer, or float with given precision). Thus it's hard to say what was expected or how wrong was the anwser.

Comment: Asking these kind of things is not exactly in the spirit of project Euler...

Comment: @darma - But that is not the question is it? The OP is stating that the out put to his algo "is wrong" without telling us how it is wrong or how he knows that is it.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn darma's point is that "the website said so" is probably how OP knows the answer is wrong. :)

Comment: @JLRishe My point is that we know no such thing. "Probably" is not a definitive answer to "how do you know".

Comment: @PhoenixReborn Of course. OP is the only one who can give a definitive answer to that. darma and I are speculating about what that definitive answer could be.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in that you are computing a power and then discarding it.

More generally, you should avoid double when solving PE problems that involve integers. Doubles are only accurate to fifteen decimal places; after that, they round off.

Better types to use are *long*, which can represent integers up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 or decimal, which can represent integers up to 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335, or BigInteger, which can represent arbitrarily large values.

Note that code typically gets slower as you use the larger and larger types.

Even more generally, now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Figure out what the output of your program should be for a very small case that you can calculate by hand. Then step through your program line by line and see where it goes wrong. That is a far more efficient way to debug a problem than asking the internet.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to think that `Math.Pow(squaresum, 2);` modifies `squaresum`. That's not so: it *returns* a square of `squaresum`, and you should assign it to `squaresum` if you want the variable to be modified.

```
squaresum = Math.Pow(squaresum, 2);
```

Also the idea of using `double` type here is not quite good, but it appears that you won't lose enough precision here to get a wrong result.